# What version of the json schema does the monaco editor support?

Tags: json, intellisense, jsonschema, monaco-editor

I cannot find the version of [json schema](https://json-schema.org/) that is supported by the monaco editor. The most information I could find was in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1799), which references a "filematch" property which [doesnt seem to exist anymore](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.json.diagnosticsoptions.html).

What version of the schema is monaco validating / providing intellisense against? draft-04? draft-06? draft-07? Can it validate all three versions dependending on the schema version specified in the json?